# Can't access to object property in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After an ajax request that's return an object I perform an `$.each` 'Cause I need to read all the object (appointment) returned. But seems that in the $.each the object is undefined, and I don't know why. This is my code of each request:

```
$.each(response.appointments, function(index, appointment)
{
      var event = 
      {
           'id': appointment['id'],
           'title': appointment['service']['name'] + ' - ' 
                  + appointment['customer']['first_name'] + ' ' 
                 + appointment['customer']['last_name'],
           'start': appointment['start_datetime'],
           'end': appointment['end_datetime'],
           'allDay': false,
           'color': '#' +  appointment['res_id']['hex_color'],
           'data': appointment  
      };
      calendarEvents.push(event);
});
```

this is the content of `response` object returned in console.log(response):

[image]

And the appointment structure:

[image]

Someone have an idea to fix this?

Comment: Looks like your `response` object isn't what you think it is - it's an array of objects, which themselves have an `appointments` property.  If this is what you're expecting, you'll need to loop over those first.  If it's not what you're expecting, perhaps there's some server side code that needs to change.

Comment: Looks like your `response` object is an array of objects, each of which containing the `appointments` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your picture-of-an-object correctly (please, include actual text next time), `response` is an *array* of objects, each containing appointments.  In that case, you'll want to say:

```
$.each(response, function(index, rsp) {
  $.each(rsp.appointments, function(index, appointment)
  {
      var event = 
      {
           'id': appointment['id'],
           'title': appointment['service']['name'] + ' - ' 
                  + appointment['customer']['first_name'] + ' ' 
                 + appointment['customer']['last_name'],
           'start': appointment['start_datetime'],
           'end': appointment['end_datetime'],
           'allDay': false,
           'color': '#' +  appointment['res_id']['hex_color'],
           'data': appointment  
      };
      calendarEvents.push(event);
  })
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah! I actually was returning an array of objects, but I thought that having encoded in json there would be no problems, well, I never stop learning! Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you referencing your object wrongly - try this:

```
$.each(response, function(index, item) {
    $.each(item.apointments, function(idx2, appointment) {
         ....
```